# LEXUS 1994 ls400

Tags: fuel-system, pump

My tank is 1/8 full. Fuel pump replaced by me. Car continues to sputter and fail.
Is there enough gas in car to prime pump?
I'm trying to make it to gas station....
What else is suspect?

Comment: Did you fit a new filter? Have you got air out of the fuel system?